# Which one should I use findOneandUpdate() and updateOne() in Express js?

Tags: mongodb, api, express, logic

Now I was making an api for a blog website, when the user tries to create a post and then update this post, the logic does not update. Please help with this

```
 updatePost: async(req, res) => {
    try {
      const errors = validationResult(req);
      if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json(errors.array());
      }

      const postId = '63dd35eae64743cef87e2f44'
      const filter = postId;
      const update = {
        title: req.body.title,
        text: req.body.text,
        imageUrl: req.body.imageUrl,
        tags: req.body.tags,
        user: req.userId,
      }

     const updateTest =  await postModel.findOneAndUpdate(filter,  update, {returnNewDocument: true, upsert:true,}).then((err) =>{
      if(err){
        console.log(err)
      }else{
        console.log(updateTest)
      }
     })
    
     res.json({       
      success: true,
      message: "Successfuly Update",
    });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.json({
        success: false,
        message: "error",  
      });
    }
  },
```

If I use the findOneandUpdate() method, no error occurs, but if I use the updateOne() method, I get an error.

```
SERVER RUN ON 7777
MongoDB Connected

StrictModeError: Path "filter" is not in schema, strict mode is `true`, and upsert is `true`.
    at cast (C:\Users\user\kamoliddin\mern stack projects\mernBlog\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast.js:279:17)
    at Query.cast (C:\Users\user\kamoliddin\mern stack projects\mernBlog\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:5341:12)
    at Query._castConditions (C:\Users\user\kamoliddin\mern stack projects\mernBlog\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2214:10)
    at model.Query._updateThunk (C:\Users\user\kamoliddin\mern stack projects\mernBlog\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4240:8)     
    at model.Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\kamoliddin\mern stack projects\mernBlog\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4379:23)     
    at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _updateOne] (C:\Users\user\kamoliddin\mern stack projects\mernBlog\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\wrapThunk.js:29:8)
```

**This is the first time I've encountered this error, so I'm at a loss as to what to do.**

Comment: Please don't post code in images.  Post it as text where it can be viewed on a phone, search indexed, copied into answers, etc...  Please edit your question to fix that.

Comment: The filter you are using in `findOneAndUpdate` seems wrong:  the filter needs to hold the name of the field and its value, in your case probably `{ postId: '63dd35eae64743cef87e2f44' }`. What is the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Your filter have to be Schema.
like this

```
 const postId = '63dd35eae64743cef87e2f44'
 const filter = {postId};
```